# RegionBoundary of a regular polygon in 3D

Tags: regions

For a regular `Polygon` in 3D I would expect some `Line` regions for the boundary

```
poly = Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}];
SimplePolygonQ[poly] (* True*)


boundary=RegionBoundary[poly]
```

but I get  a Polygon-object

`boundary = Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {1, 2, 3}]`

instead.

Expecting a one dimensional region `RegionMeasure` evaluates  to my surprise

```
RegionMeasure[boundary,1] (* \[Infinity]*)
RegionMeasure[boundary,2] (*  Sqrt[3]/2 *)
```

My questions

Why  `RegionMeasure[boundary,1]` doesn't give the correct length of the boundary?

Shouldn't `RegionMeasure[boundary,2]` be undefined?

Is there a simple way to get Line-objects as boundary

Thanks

Comment: `Region /@ {#, RegionBoundary[#]} &@Disk[]` works as one would expect.

Comment: Same with `Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}] // RegionBoundary`

Comment: `Perimeter@boundary` works. Maybe it is looking for a 3D region with some volume to it. `RegionDimension@poly` being `2` might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that only `RegionPlot3D` can recognize its boundary.

```
poly = Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}];
plot = RegionPlot3D[poly, PlotStyle -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
plot // DiscretizeGraphics // RegionMeasure
```

[image]

> `4.24264`